# how configure transactionmanager for multiple databases

Tags: java, datasource, entitymanager

I have one transaction manager with many entitymanager one for each database but if there is any fails it does not access any, how I can resolve this problem?

```
@Primary
@Bean
    public ChainedTransactionManager transactionManager( ) {
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(
        new JpaTransactionManager(emR01.getEntityManagerFactory()), new
          JpaTransactionManager(emR02.getEntityManagerFactory()), new
          JpaTransactionManager(emR03.getEntityManagerFactory()), new
          JpaTransactionManager(emR04.getEntityManagerFactory()), new
          JpaTransactionManager(emR05.getEntityManagerFactory()), new
          JpaTransactionManager(emR06.getEntityManagerFactory()), new
          JpaTransactionManager(emR07.getEntityManagerFactory()), new
          JpaTransactionManager(emR08.getEntityManagerFactory()), new
          JpaTransactionManager(emR09.getEntityManagerFactory())
         
                );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple transaction managers while calling the below code into loop and register a unique bean for everyone

at run time

```
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

bean register runtime

```
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
```

BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory;
registry.removeBeanDefinition("txn01");
context.registerBean("txn01", PlatformTransactionManager.class, () -> transactionManager());

Comment: in java 6 I cant  use  PlatformTransactionManager.class, () -> transactionManager());          
 what is equivalent?